# Excel rows not getting deleted using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to delete excel rows if they have zeros. Few of the rows got deleted, but i do see some more rows not getting deleted. Below is the code. Any light on this.

```
for row in range(2, sheet2.max_row+1):
    cell2 = sheet2.cell(row, 15)
    if cell2.value == 0:
        sheet2.delete_rows(row, 1)
        print(f"THe cell valaue is {row} {cell2.value}")

wb2.save('New_Overhead_cal.xlsx')
```

One Update...
When I copy & paste the for loop 5 times before I save the excel file the rows are deleted. So it means that whether the rows are shifted after deletion causing this issue?

Comment: loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Because each time you delete a row, while your row counter moves forward, the rest of the rows shift upward, causing your for loop to miss some items. As @Scott Craner suggests, looping backwards should work.

The same problem happens when you try to delete something from an array while using a for loop.

```
for row in range(sheet2.max_row, 1, -1):
    cell2 = sheet2.cell(row, 15)
    if cell2.value == 0:
        sheet2.delete_rows(row, 1)
        print(f"THe cell valaue is {row} {cell2.value}")
```

You can also do it with `while`.

```
row = 2
while(row <= sheet2.max_row):
    cell2 = sheet2.cell(row, 15)
    if cell2.value == 0:
        sheet2.delete_rows(row, 1)
        print(f"THe cell valaue is {row} {cell2.value}")
    else:
        row += 1
```